# save a column to database using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark to calculate a set of data. I have just calculated a column of the table.

For example, the table in my database is named people with schema (id,weight,height,salary,...,) and id is the primary key in the table "people". I have just calculated part of the value of the column "salary" and i'd like to update the data in the database.

My result is a dataframe named "ID_Salary" with schema(id,salary). It is sure that all the id in "ID_Salary" is already in the table "people". All I'd like to do is to update the table.

How to write the code to update the part of the table "people" using the dataframe "ID_Salary" I got?

Comment: If i understood your question correctly, you want to update your database table after some computation. In that case, i don't think DataFrame is the right choice of framework. May be you can do that with big data data-stores like HBase or Accumulo.

Comment: thx, i think my question is not good. Appreciate for your answer.